# pattern to exclude specific files

Tags: python, tensorflow, glob

I'm trying to create regex which will list all `.jpg` in some directory except few files(static, not a pattern).

So, I've wrote this:(Python)

```
"^(?!358097_sat!823133_sat!140860_sat).*jpg$"
"^(?!358097_sat|823133_sat|140860_sat).*jpg$"
```

I want to list all JPEG files except for:

- 358097_sat
- 823133_sat
- 140860_sat

**But it gives me an error saying that no file found matching this pattern.**

Here is the complete string and error message:

```
No files matched pattern: ../input/dataset/valid/^(?!358097_sat!823133_sat!140860_sat).*jpg$
```

I'm actually passing this regex to a tf-function:

```
tf.data.Dataset.list_files(dataset_path + val_data + "^(?!358097_sat|823133_sat|140860_sat).*jpg$", seed=SEED)
# dataset_path = "../input/dataset/"
# val_data = "valid/"
```

Complete error:

*InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'No files matched pattern: ../input/dataset/valid/^(?!358097_sat|823133_sat|140860_sat).*jpg$'*

Here is the function reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files

Comment: You may need to substitute `!` with `|`. Does `^(?!358097_sat|823133_sat|140860_sat).*jpg$` work for you?

Comment: @lemon it didn't work... i forgot to mention it on the que

Comment: If it tries to get these kind of files `../input/dataset/valid/^(?!358097_sat!823133_sat!140860_sat).*jpg$`, then it means that it's not interpreting the regex as such, can you share your Python code?

Comment: @lemon added the related code

Comment: The link you've provided explicitly states that the pattern should be _"representing the filename glob"_ - that's _not_ regex. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static method `list_files` expects a string or list of strings containing [globs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), *not* regular expressions.
See also [filename matching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch).

Filename matching using *globs* does not have a way to negate a match. So you will have to write a custom function to do that.

You could use e.g. `glob.glob()` to generate a list of JPEG files, and then filter out the ones that match your strings.

```
ignore = ("358097_sat", "823133_sat", "140860_sat")

files = [f for f in glob.glob("*.jpg") if not any(j in f for j in ignore)]
```